# How to install Mongodb version 3.4.17 in Ubuntu 20.04.4

Tags: linux, database, mongodb, ubuntu

I have tried a lot but there is no way in which I can install mongoDB 3.4.* versions on my Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

Plz help me in that.

**I have tried this:**

`sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 0C49F3730359A14518585931BC711F9BA15703C6`

`echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.4 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.4.list`

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install mongodb-org`

**But it was giving an error after the last line's execution:**

`Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree        Reading state information... Done Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming. The following information may help to resolve the situation: The following packages have unmet dependencies: mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-shell but it is not going to be installed Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed Depends: mongodb-org-tools but it is not going to be installed E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: Please provider some more information including the error message, the commands you are running etc.

Comment: Hi, @tuxtimo I have provided some more info, plz have a look and plz give me some solution to my problem, I am really feeling very helpless.

Answer (score -1):

Easy steps:

1. Download the latest(3.4.23) binary [archive](https://fastdl.mongodb.org/linux/mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1604-3.4.23.tgz) packaged for ubuntu 16.04
   ( There was no ubuntu 20.04 at the time when mongodb 3.4.23 was packaged )
2. Copy in example folder:

   ```
   cp *23.tgz /installDir/
   ```
3. Untar the package in the target folder:

   ```
   tar zxvf mongodb-linux-x86_64-ubuntu1604-3.4.23.tgz
   ```
4. Prepare mongodb.conf file with expected parameters, there is many examples , but here is something minimal:

   ```
   processManagement:
      fork: true
   net:
      bindIp: localhost
      port: 27017
   storage:
      dbPath: /installDir/data/
   systemLog:
      destination: file
      path: "/installDir/log/mongod.log"
      logAppend: true
   storage:
      journal:
         enabled: true
   ```

You need to create the /installDir/data & /installDir/log folders , mongodb will not start if those folders are not found.

5. Start the binary or as a service depending on your needs.

   ```
   /installDir/xxx/bin/mongod --config mongodb.conf
   ```
6. When you dont needed it ( it is pretty old version already , at the time of my answer there is 5.0.8 current and 6.0 release canidate ) you can remove the /installDir/ folder with:

   ```
   rm -rf /installDir/*
   ```

mongod 3.4 will need the ubuntu 16 OS openssl ssl&crypto 1.0.0 libraries,  you may download and copy them from official [debian archive](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb)  extract and create symblic link so the mongod 3.4 to find them:

```
     wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/o/openssl1.0/libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb
     dpkg -x libssl1.0.0_1.0.2n-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb /installDir/
     sudo ln -s /installDir/libssl.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0
     sudo ln -s /installDir/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /usr/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
```

P.S.
I just now have seen you need the concrete mongodb version 3.4.17 , process is same just replace 23 with 17